# How do I have regex to match exact multiple domains without anything in front or end?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'd like to whitelist domains and I have this list as

`(domain1.com|domain2.com)`

However, it will still match to

`ci.domain1.com`

https://regex101.com/r/A2IOJE/1/

I'm writing the code in node.js

Here's the code

```
new RegExp('(domain1.com|domain2.com)', 'igm').test('ci.domain1.com');
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to add `^` (start of string) & `$` (end of string):

```
/^(domain1.com|domain2.com)$/
```

```js
console.log(
new RegExp('^(domain1.com|domain2.com)$', 'igm').test('ci.domain1.com'),
new RegExp('^(domain1.com|domain2.com)$', 'igm').test('domain1.com'),
new RegExp('^(domain1.com|domain2.com)$', 'igm').test('domain2.com')
)
```

Answer (score 4):

With anchors and optional `www` matching at the start you can use this regex:

```
/^(?:www\.)?(?:domain1|domain2)\.com$/i
```

Also dot before `com` needs to be escaped to avoid matching any character.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/A2IOJE/3)

**RegEx Breakup:**

- `^`: Start
- `(?:www\.)?`: Match optional `www` at the start of domains
- `(?:domain1|domain2)`: Match `domain1` or `domain2`
- `\.com`: Match literal text `.com`
- `$`: End